# How to clean memory of browser in javascript from objects and classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory, browser, asynchronous

I making a quest game with three scenes. The player can move from scene to scene and go back. (like a well known classic quests: Neverhood,Machinarium,The Curse of Monkey Island) 
Each scene have it's own objects, classes and bags of graphic elements. Here is how look a scripts for one scene.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.gamequery-0.5.0.2.js"></script>

<!-- ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////                 Charecters            ////////////////////
     /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/charecters/player.js" id="player_anime"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="js/charecters/mama.js" ></script>


    <!-- ////////////////////////////////////////////////
  ///////////                 Scene globals            ////////////////////
   /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scene_globals/scene2/audio.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scene_globals/scene2/background.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scene_globals/scene2/scene.js"></script>

    <!-- ////////////////////////////////////////////////
   ///////////                 Game controls            ////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/game_control.js"></script>
```

I want to load scripts for each scene asynchronously in order to solve the problem of memory usage. But i realized that even if I destroy all the scripts and load others for next scene, the objects and graphic elements are still stay in memory.

Here is the general algorithm:

1) loading graphic and scripts for first scene.
2) user pass the first scene
3) erase all the objects, scripts and graphic of first scene
4) loading all that needs for second scene

There is another way to make it: Instead of asyncronious solution, i can just put all stuff for each scene into iframe. So when the iframe reloads to next scene all objects and graphic erase. But here is another problem- how to use all the objects and graphic in iframe from parent page. (There is some interaction that i have)

I hope that my bad English is good enough to make the question clear.

Waiting for eny suggestions.

Comment: There are no "classes" in JavaScript. And you cannot erase scripts other than by unloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you *cannot*.

However you could use some hints and generally used techniques to trigger garbage collection.

First thing is the use of the `delete` operator which is used to delete a property of an object. It has nothing to do with the `delete` operator used in languages such as `C++` but could be used in case you will not need a variable in the future. This will delete every references to this variable but not directly the value contained by this variable though. Meaning that :

```
// creating the property i in the global object
i = 0;

obj = {
  x : 10,
  y : 20
};

delete i;
// deletes the property i from the global object
// At this point, you are giving a hint to the garbage collector that he 
// can now free the memory associated with i because it is no 
// longer referenced.

delete obj.x; // removes the property 'x' of obj
obj.x = 10; // undefined reference to 'x' in obj
```

Next thing could simply be an intelligent management of your variables. For instance :

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];
// using array and the values contained by array ...
array = null;
// this will give a hint to the garbage collector that currently, 
// the value pointed by array ( [1,2,3] ) is not referenced to anymore 
// and can be freed.
```

Note that you cannot in `Javascript` (as in other managed languages) *explicitely* free the memory for a variable or an object. The garbage collector will in the big majority of the cases, perform very well.

In your case, why not using *lazy resource loading* so you can load the code needed by each scene on demand ? This will have both advantages of being faster in terms of page loading, and you will not be worried by your problem anymore.

Comment: -1. Either http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/, or understand the difference between variables and properties.

Comment: It still states that "*`delete i;` frees the memory associated with i*", and I'm sorry if I can't watch all the posts which I've voted on (though I certainly try)

Comment: The ´delete´ operator does not free memory, and i did not said that. Instead, I said that ´delete´ will remove the property ´i´ from the global object, thus giving a hint to the garbage collector to free the memory used by ´i´.

Comment: OK, I see now that you're explicitly using the global object. But one should usually not do that, and would need to watch out not to use `var` "accidentally" for that global variable. Nullifying, as you do with `array`, is by far the better approach.

Answer (score 0):

I would aim to adopt a strategy something like this :

- Adopt the [Module Pattern](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/)
- Write a static, generic module, suitable for all scenes
- For each scene, write a javascript file containing an appropriately constructed module containing all the data/functions specific to that scene.
- Include in the generalized framework the means to load (using eg. JSONP) the appropriate module for the required scene.

With the Module Pattern, you would normally make sure that a module doesn't "overwrite" another module of the same name. However, that's exactly what you want in this case.

On loading a new module, garbage collection will look after deletion of the "overwritten" module.

As javascript's garbage collection is somewhat lazy, you could force it with the `delete` command prior to loading a new scene. The only provision you need to make is to ensure the modules are defined as properties of an outer `project` namespace (as is typical with the module pattern).

Correctly implemented, you will place just **one member in the global namespace** (plus one or more for each utility/library object such as jQuery).

Comment: [`delete` is nothing to force garbage collection, but an operator for properties!](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/)